# Has always been and forever will be valuable...(phrase)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, phrase-usage

Let's say you are marveled at how technology helps people everyday.

> It blows me away just to think how technology helps people on a daily basis, such as transportation and communication via cellphones or computers. These things inspire innovators to do more to become more efficient than they currently are. I believe, technology **has always been** and **forever will be** valuable to humanity.

Are the bold letters, as *past to present* and *future* events, in correct usage? I just heard these 2 bold letters, BUT I am not sure if I can use them correctly to say what I really mean without any trouble of misunderstandings or the like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two phrases

> **has always been**
>   **forever will be**

are both correct and refer to what has happened before and what will happen in the future. Usually the two are often found connected together as in the original text.  In biblical references

> **forver shall be**

is often found.